# Is "hadn't got" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, british-english

Yesterday in my English class, I tried to say 'I hadn't got that book' and my teacher told me my sentence was incorrect, she said I should say 'I didn't have that book'.

I bought Grammarly, and it shows me my sentence is correct. Or maybe there is a difference between 'I didn't have that book' and 'I hadn't got that book'.

I would like to know the opinion of a British person.

Comment: Past simple ([**I didn't have time**](https://www.engvid.com/basic-english-grammar-had-didnt-have-did-have/)) vs Past perfect ([**I hadn't had time**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/grammar/online-grammar/past-perfect-simple-with-time-expressions) / **got**)

Comment: @Barmar You can use "got" *in the perfect* to mean "have/possess," but this is much more common in British English than in American English. [See here.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have)

Comment: In British English, the form *gotten* is usually avoided in favor of *got,* though *gotten* is spreading across the Atlantic. This means that, in British English, "has got" can be ambiguous between "has" (the idiom "has got") and "has received" (with the past participle of "get").

Comment: @alphabet Good point, as in "I've got rhythm".

Comment: I'll let someone British take this on, given the dialectical variation, since the asker specified that dialect. @Barmar

Comment: @alphabet I didn't notice that detail, either.

Comment: In AmE I would normally use "I had gotten", "I hadn't gotten", but I would understand it if someone said "I hadn't got." E.g. "I hadn't got the joke yet, but I laughed anyway." In that context (getting a joke), you need "get" and not "have" (one "gets" a joke when one understands why it's funny). For a book, you can either "get" the book (to come into posession of it) or you can have it (to be in posession of it).

Comment: Buying Grammarly just gives you a stream of poor advice. Save your money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should provide the context in which you uttered the sentence *I hadn't got that book*.

If you intended to describe a past perfect situation of you getting that book, your sentence would work in British English.

But if you intended to describe a past situation of you possessing that book, your sentence might still work in British English but might not be terribly idiomatic.

> The preterite is certainly possible (*She had got too much work to do*), but it is fairly uncommon: ***have** got* occurs predominantly in the present tense.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 112).

Comment: Not common isn’t the same at all as not idiomatic! It’s perfectly idiomatic in British English - for me at least.

Comment: Indeed. "I haven't got [one]" is a perfectly idiomatic, though colloquial, way of saying that you do not possess something.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks for your input. But if you find it perfectly idiomatic and it's still fairly uncommon, does it mean that you're in the minority? Also, would you advise someone who attends an English class to use it?

Comment: No, something idiomatic but not common will strike people as idiomatic! "Tendril" is not a common word but it's perfectly idiomatic. Inverted third conditionals are relatively rare but perfectly idiomatic etc etc

Comment: And it's actually extremely common in idioms in which it has the very same meaning. Take for example ["hadn't got a clue"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hadn%27t+got+a+clue%22&client=safari&rls=en&ei=_HyAZMBJgrHyAqvIpegK&ved=0ahUKEwjAt_GYmbH_AhWCmFwKHStkCa0Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22hadn%27t+got+a+clue%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEMgUIABCiBDIFCAAQogQ6CAgAEKIEELADOgoIIRCgARDDBBAKOggIABCJBRCiBEoECEEYAVD4C1i5H2DDJ2gCcAB4AIABgwGIAaMEkgEDNi4xmAEAoAEBwAEByAEE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks! Good to know!